# Slickgrid editor finish event

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I have set `Editors.Text` or edit.

```
 {id: "label", name: "name", field: "label",editor: Editors.Text,width: 80},
```

This enables editing for field on browser.

But how can I catch when editing is finished??

I am checking the event [list](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Grid-Events) of slickgrid.

However can't find the appropriate event.

How can I catch the event after editing columns??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that there is no generic event for this - probably not a bad idea to add one. I suspect it is expected that you would write a custom editor and add the event directly to that rather than adding it to the grid.

I assume you want to update some related data or UI when the editing is complete?

[Edit]

The editor has events encapsulated in it for doing this - the grid uses a plugin model with `loadValue` and `applyValue` to read/write the data source. I'll post an example of my personal text editor here, as it may help. Note that I have written a data provider for my personal grid to allow it to interface to several custom data objects - this isn't in the standard one you should be using, which is [here](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid).

```
function TextEditor(args) {
    var $input;
    var defaultValue;
    var scope = this;

    this.init = function () {
        $input = $("<INPUT type=text class='editor-text' />")
      .appendTo(args.container)
      .on("keydown.nav", function (e) {
          if (e.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.LEFT || e.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.RIGHT) {
              e.stopImmediatePropagation();
          }
      })
      .focus()
      .select();
        $input.width(args.container.clientWidth); /* mod */
    };

    this.destroy = function () {
        $input.remove();
    };

    this.focus = function () {
        $input.focus();
    };

    this.getValue = function () {
        return $input.val();
    };

    this.setValue = function (val) {
        $input.val(val);
    };

    this.loadValue = function () {
        defaultValue = args.grid.getDataProvider().getValueByColName(args.rowIndex, args.column.field);
        defaultValue = defaultValue || "";
        $input.val(defaultValue);
        $input[0].defaultValue = defaultValue;
        $input.select();
    };

    this.serializeValue = function () {
        return $input.val();
    };

    this.applyValue = function (state) {
        args.grid.getDataProvider().setValueByColName(args.rowIndex, args.column.field, state);
    };

    this.isValueChanged = function () {
        return (!($input.val() == "" && defaultValue == null)) && ($input.val() != defaultValue);
    };

    this.validate = function () {
        if (args.column.validator) {
            var validationResults = args.column.validator($input.val());
            if (!validationResults.valid) {
                return validationResults;
            }
        }

        return {
            valid: true,
            msg: null
        };
    };

    this.init();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I want to update the database entity according to the editing on the browser. I am surprised that there is no callback after finishing editing.(If so, how they update the database??? , adding 'update' button?? it looks awkward.)

Comment: I copy and paste TextEditor function from slickgrid source and name it `myTextEditor` then, put Ajax to change data in `this.isValueChanged` function. it works as I intended. thank you very much.